# How to get data from Object's field using variable?

Tags: php

F.e.
I have object $game, there are 3 screenshots
$game->screen1, $game->screen2, $game->screen3

I need to get data like this $game['screen'.$num], but in the Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array for this:

```
$game->screen = array($screen1, $screen2, $screen3);

$game->screen[$num];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```
$game->screen2 = 'this is screen2';
$num = 2;
echo $game->{'screen' . $num}; // "this is screen2"

$game->screen3 = 'this is screen3';
$num = 3;
echo $game->{'screen' . $num}; // "this is screen3"
```